# Class that returns arrays

Tags: java, arrays, return

Im very very new to java. Im trying to make a class that returns some info about a few movies (all this info is stored in array). Im stuck and dont know what to do. Here is my code

Movies class:

```
public class Movie {

    String[] Director;
    String[] Name;
    String[] realeaseDate;
    String[] lastShow;


    public Movie()
    {
        String[] Director={"George Romero","Woody Allen","Steven Speilberg","James Cameron"};
        String[] Name={"Diary of the Dead","Midnight in Paris","War of the Worlds","Terminator 2 - Judgment Day"};
        String[] realeaseDate={"Dec 31 1999","Dec 28 1999","Dec 15 1999","Dec 10 1999"};
        String[] lastShow={"Jan 13 2000","Jan 29 2000","Jan 23 2000","Jan 15 2000"};

    }

    public String getDirector()
    {
        return Director;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getRealease()
    {
        return realeaseDate;
    }

    public String getLast()
    {
        return lastShow;
    }

}
```

Now here is my Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Movie movies = new Movie();

        System.out.println("Avaliable movies"+newLine);

        System.out.println("Director: "+ movies.getDirector()+newLine+"Name :"+ movies.getName()+ newLine + "Realease Date: "+ movies.getRealease()+newLine+"Last Show :"+ movies.getLast()+newLine);

    }

}
```

I want the result to be like:

All available movies

George...
Diary of...
dec..
januar...

Steven..
sdafsda...
Dec...
Jan..

.
.
.

Comment: You're shadowing your fields in your constructor. Also check your return types. Also, check how to print out the contents of an array. Also, look into encapsulation.

Comment: In other words, change `String[] Director={"George Romero","Woody ...` to `Director={"George Romero","Woody ...`

Comment: Also worth noting that you've defined a `String[] Director` but your method `getDirector()` returns a `String`.

Comment: I think what you really want is an array of movies... Not a movie that holds arrays for a bunch of different movies

Answer (score 4):

Since you are new to java I would also recommend treating the movie class as a single object(not an array of movies) and then store the values in a list of movie objects.  This way each movie object contains just the information about a single movie.  This would be the more object oriented approach

```
public class Movie {

    String Director;
    String Name;
    String releaseDate;
    String lastShow;


    public Movie(String director, String name, String release, String lastShow)
    {
        this.Director = director;
        this.Name = name;
        this.releaseDate = release;
        this.lastShow = lastShow;
    }

    public String getDirector()
    {
        return Director;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getRelease()
    {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public String getLast()
    {
        return lastShow;
    }

}
```

And then your main file might look like the following:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Movie firstMovie= new Movie("George Romero","Diary of the Dead", "Dec 31 1999","Jan 13 2000" );
        Movie secondMovie = new Movie("test", "name", "date", "date");
        ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        //add movies to list

        System.out.println("Avaliable movies"+newLine);

        //loop through each movie in movies

        //print information about each movie

    }

}
```

I will leave the rest of the implementation up to an exercise for you, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is the only right answer so far. Clearly the OP is confused about OOP

Comment: @Cruncher I agree, removing answer.

Comment: @kevin94, you should accept this answer. (It's never too late.)