# regular expression python that accepts everything

Tags: python, expression, state-machine

I want to write a re that accepts everything that is between parenthesis. My re is: r''\'([^&]+'\')' (ingnore the '' in the backslash)

I had to put that random character so it will accept everything except that. How can I write it so it accepts EVERYTHING including that character. Thanks.

Comment: do you know how to accept an answer? Don't worry about me and my answer, but you should go back and accept the answer for your question from last year: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146970/class-that-returns-arrays. It's only right.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
r'\([^)]+\)'
```

Because you don't want to accept the close parenthesis.

Also:

> (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

So:

```
r'\(.+\)'
```

Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: That could work, but for what I'm doing there is not always a pair of parenthesis. Isn't there something for everything?

Comment: The regex you gave will not match without a close paren, you are explicitly requiring it.